# how can I set the data type of parameters of Dense layer to float16?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to use Tensorflow [Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) layer with float16 parameters. The default data types of bias and weights are both float32, I tried setting the data type by setting the initializer `tf.truncated_normal_initializer(dtype=tf.float16)` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
import tensorflow as tf
A = tf.get_variable(name='foo', shape=[3, 3])
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=A, units=3, kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(dtype=tf.float16))
varis = tf.trainable_variables(scope=None)
print(varis[1])  # <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3) dtype=float32_ref>
```

How can I use Tensorflow [Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) with float16 parameters?

Comment: did you try tf.layers.dense(..., dtype=tf.float16)? It seems that this keyword will propagate all the way down to keras.engine.base_layer and will take effect

Comment: @y.selivonchyk I tried but it gives me this error TypeError: dense() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this, that is to set the input data type of the dense layer to `tf.float16`

```
import tensorflow as tf
A = tf.get_variable(name='foo', shape=[3, 3], dtype=tf.float16)
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=A, units=3)
varis = tf.trainable_variables(scope=None)
print(varis[1])  # <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3) dtype=float16_ref>
```